# Joining 2 lists to get (a,d,b,e,c,f) instead of (a,b,c,d,e,f)

Tags: string, list, join, python-3.x, concatenation

In Python 3, say we have 2 lists:

```
list1=[a,b,c]
list2=[d,e,f]
```

I want to join them to get:

```
new_list=[a,d,b,e,c,f]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: those are tuples, not lists.

Comment: @Didi Bui:  You can edit this question if you want better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> sum(zip(list1, list2), ())
('a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'f')
```

Comment: darn it, I was about to post this and you beat me to it :P +1

Answer (score 1):

Ignacio's solution is fine, but if you're dealing with big lists:

```
>>> tuple(x for y in zip(list1,list2) for x in y)
('a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'f')
```